# Indexing millions of records from multiple tables in Lucene.Net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, lucene, lucene.net

We are having trouble indexing records from our database into Lucene Index. This is  our current situation.

We need to index data from multiple tables from database. All of them are connected with foreign keys, with 1 to n relations. Full Record, that we would like to index, is a combination of data from those table. Problem is, we have tens of millions records in a database. Our approaches:

1. Selecting all records with LEFT JOIN query, then we are using

```cs
IndexWriter.AddDocument(IEnumerable<IIndexableField> doc)
```

method to add those record in a batch to our Index. That works ok with only one table - when we are joining multiple tables, we are receiving timeouts when connecting to database, and our admins are telling us, that we are killing server with our queries. All our joins have keys specified, and there is nothing that we can do to improve in here - there is too much data to load in a single query.

2. Select data one table at a time. That is also fine, but we are either ending up with multiple indexes - each of them containing only part of data we want - or one index with multiple "incomplete" records. If we instead of inserting multiple incomplete records try to update existing:

```cs
IndexWriter.UpdateDocument(Term term, IEnumerable<IIndexableField> doc)
```

it takes too much time. Update is really slow in this case.

So the question is, **what would be the best approach in indexing data from multiple tables that contains millions of records**?

Comment: The computer holding the Lucene index has enough memory to hold all rows from all tables in c# objects in memory at the same time? If this is the case you can build your final data in memory by joining it using dictionaries and write it to the index in one go (several batches).

Comment: No, keeping all records in memory is not an option. There is too much data.

Comment: 1 Gb of memory can hold millions of records. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Pesca. Spin up an x1e.32xlarge amazon EC2 instance with 3,904 Gb of RAM memory and consider if keeping all records in memory is an option or not :-)

Comment: @Pesca. If keeping all records in memory is still not an option, please consider using disk persisted dictionaries. There is an implementation using ESENT: https://github.com/Microsoft/ManagedEsent. You can also use Key Value stores such as RocksDb https://github.com/warrenfalk/rocksdb-sharp. Or more specialized persisent hash tables like https://github.com/luispedro/diskhash

Comment: diskhash doesn't have C# implementation. Esent is really slow in writing - reading is ok though. RocksDb looks promising - I will take a look at it. Thanks.